# How to change the size of container with mouse dragging in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, drag

When you drag the edge of container with mouse ,how to implement changing the size of container?

Comment: You have to use/create custom components as your requirement. I have given some links in which source code enabled..

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this Document](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2007/03/creating_resizable_and_draggab.html) about Creating Resizable and Draggable Flex Components. 
Refer [Resizable TitleWindow](http://flexponential.com/2010/01/10/resizable-titlewindow-in-flex-4/)
This may help You..